# Is there a command in /system/bin to wipe cache?

Tags: command-line, cache

Is there a command in /system/bin to perform cache clearing?

Comment: If by wiping you mean erasing the contents of partition mounted at /cache, you can delete them simply from any file explorer or commandline (terminal emulator / adb shell). It needs root. Or if filesystem on your cache partition is ext4, you can use /system/bin/make_ext4fs to format the partition (what custom recoveries do usually). But it can be dangerous in some situations. Some apps save logs etc. there.